# Form save is not adding user to model

Tags: python, django

I have a django Model and ModelForm, but when I make a new body, everything works, except the User is not created. All post.user attributes return none. I am using the contrib.auth to login user, which works as in my html user.is_authenticated works

I tried using:

> form.user=request.user
> form.save()

to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField(max_length=140)
    timestamp = models.DateField(db_index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post {}>'.format(self.body)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post', args=[str(self.id)])
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Post
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class PostForm(ModelForm):
    def clean_body(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['body']
        if len(data) > 140:
            raise ValidationError('More than 140 characters')
        return data
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['body']
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.urls import reverse
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your views here.

@login_required
def index(request):
    '''deal with post method first'''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('index'))
    
    else:
        form = PostForm
    
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 3)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    context = {
        'form':form,
        'page_obj':page_obj
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `form` has no `user`, you should patch the `.instance` wrapped in the form, so:

```
@login_required
def index(request):
    '''deal with post method first'''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
    # …
```

You might want to use the [**`auto_now_add=True`** parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields,/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) for the `timestamp`:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField(max_length=140)
    timestamp = models.DateField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    # …
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: what's the difference between ```timestamp = models.DateField(db_index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)``` and ```timestamp = models.DateField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)```?

Comment: @Jjkivai: it will set `editable=False` and `blank=True`, such that by default the field will not show up in forms for example. But in general you can see it as slightly more "high level", which is often better, since if new features arive, they can do specific things for a `DateField(auto_now_add=True)`. Finally for a `DateTimeField`, it will make use of `timezone.now`, which is a timezone-sensitive variant of `datetime.now`.